# Loading images libgdx

Tags: java, android, textures, libgdx

So I have two separate programs, but I'm having trouble loading images on one and not the other.

In the first one I have an image that I load as a texture in the mainGameScreen.java that is 800x480 pixels.

```
Texture img1;
img1= new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bg1.png"));
```

And it loads with no problem at all

So first question why does one load and the other not even though the first is just kind of a landscape version of the second.

In my second program I have an image that is 480x800. I load it however in Images.java.

```
public class Images{
    public static Texture img2;
    public static void load(){
        img2 = new Texture (Gdx.files.internal("bg2.PNG"))
```

It raises an error `Texture width and height must be a power of 2`

But then if I change the size of the image to 512x512 then it won't raise any errors, but I then get a blank screen with kind of static colors going through it when I render it.

And then in my MyRenderer.java file I have a batch that I draw it to my batch.

```
public class MyRenderer{
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    public MyRenderer(){
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    public void update;
        camera.update();
        batch.SetProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(Images.img2, 0, 0);
        batch.end ();
```

Comment: Are you using OpenGl ES 2.0 in both programms? It seems like OpenGL ES 2.0 does not require "Power of Two" Textures anymore, OpenGL Es 1.x does. SO just compare the OpenGL versions of your 2 programs.

Comment: @Springrbua Thanks I'll try that when I get home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image should be power of two if you are using OpenGl ES 1 and 1.x, you can set openGLES2 to true in your desktop or android configuration, this assumes that you want to use from android 2.3 to up, but for older yes ES 1.x and power of two, so I suggest that you use GLES 2 since in near future on new libgdx probably the will remove old GLES.

first make sure you dispose SpriteBatch & Texture on dispose() add dispose() method to your Images class and dispose all texture, since you are using static image you have one texture in whole class so remove static and use field, Second I suggest that you use Sprite for easy control of image and use batch to render that sprite. third you are using static image in one class that is I think is not good, use private field for texture.

another suggestion is to use Game and Screen for better managing of different levels.

Comment: Just FYI I have separate class for the Game, but then I have a class for MainMenuScreen and then a class GameScreen, but thanks for the info.